# import degree symbol (°) from excel or csv file to mssql database

Tags: excel, csv, import, degrees

I have a field in my csv file which contains the text: Frozen at 20°C

but when i import into my database it appears as: Frozen at 20�C

anyone know how i can keep the correct degree symbol?

my import code looks like this

```
string fieldValue = csv[i].Trim();
```

Comment: How is the file encoded ? Can you open it with an hex editor and tell us what code represents the ° sign ?

Comment: And for that matter, what encoding are you using in the database, as if the relevant column is varchar/char/text rather than nvarchar/nchar/ntext, this could also have an effect, though I'd bet on it being a matter of the CSV file's encoding as @Stephane suggests.

Comment: im not sure how the file is encoded, im working on 32-bit windows xp and excel 2003. I opened the file using HxD Hex Editor and when i highlight the degree symbol the hex appears to be B0? also the column im saving to is ntext.

Comment: Ok. That means you're using ASCII and a code page compatible with CP437. How to you perform the import in your database ? How do you display the result ?

Comment: I am using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv (CSV Reader) to read my csv file. Then simply looping over every row, reading each value into a string and saving it using Linq.

Comment: Check your import framework documentation: there must be a place where you describe the text encoding of the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to specify Encoding.Default when creating my stream reader

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.Default), true)
```

Thanks for all the help Stephane you got me there in the end.