# VB.Net store column with Degrees sign in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a CSV File I am parsing (it's specific, so I can't just dump it in).  In one of the fields, there can be a degrees sign. As an example:

```
TR,TIC593_SP_TREND,,TIC593_SP,0,200,°F,1,YES,NONE,NONE,NONE,,,,NONE,YES,NO,REJECT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

That is what It looks like in NotePad and I need to be able to replicate that into the database.  All of the fields I am inserting into are NVARCHAR(Max).

**EDIT**

What I need is for the Degrees sign to be stored in SQL Server as a degrees sign, so that when I pull it out, it will go into the newly generated CSV file as a degrees sign instead of funky characters (ï¿½F is what I see when I export the same field from SQL)

**/EDIT**

Code-Wise, I am doing the following:

1. Iterating through all lines in the CSV File to pull out the lines I want to go into the database
2. Creating a Datatable:

   ```vb
   Dim sqlstr = "select * from Tags where id=-1"
   adap = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, conn)

   Dim dt As New DataTable
   adap.Fill(dt)
   ```
3. Creating a New DataRow

   ```vb
   Dim _new As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                       For i As Integer = 0 To columnsNames.Length - 1
                           Application.DoEvents()
                           Dim colName As String = columnsNames(i).Replace("!", "")
                           Dim colVal As String = columnValues(i)
                           If colName <> "" Then


                               _new("NodeName") = nodeName
                               _new("FileName") = FileName
                               _new(colName) = colVal



                           End If
   ```
4. Adding to the Datatable:

   ```vb
   dt.Rows.Add(_new)
   ```
5. And, Finally, committing the information to the table:

   ```vb
   dim combld as new SQLCommandBuilder(adap)
   adap.Update(dt)
   ```

I'm sure there has to be an easy way, just haven't come across it with all the searching I've done (which, hopefully, my search techniques are not the problem!).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, get rid of that Application.DoEvents... that has no business being there. Second, so what is the problem? I don't see any thing resembling a question or a problem. Also, I can't say that I'm a fan of the select * either, but hey, it's your code, not mine.

Comment: What does the degrees (`°`) character have to do with the question as well? Why would it being there make a difference?

Comment: Is this likely a duplicate to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830512/import-degree-symbol-from-excel-or-csv-file-to-mssql-database

Comment: Agreed, this wasn't originally my code... I did not add the Application.DoEvents or the select * either.  I'm just tasked with fixing a bungled job.  I updated the post to show my question - which is similar to the title of the post. Checking out that other post now.

Comment: The degree symbol is fluff, it's display fodder/formatting.  It is not information/data which is all a csv should have.  If you're trying to fix a "bungled job" I'd start with the csv content first.  For me? all I'd take is the letter.  Anything you want to do with the CSV data once it's in the table in terms of output formatting should be handled by what ever code is responsible for display formatting.

Comment: Thanks.  It isn't fluff in the quality industry and is necessary (since the field is used for all units of measure and is required for import into the system. I did use the other thread, put encoding on both sides (import and export) and all is well.  thanks.

Comment: You should probably show the code that creates the output csv.  I'm guessing the problem is there.

Comment: As long as the CSV file and the SQL database are both using Unicode encoding there shouldn’t be any problem reading the degrees symbol from the file and storing it in the database.